# Determine type of Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have two Enumerators and a method that takes an enumerator. They are called ABC and DEF and the method is called TestMethod(Enum myEnum). Code is below:

```
public enum ABC
{
    Zero,
    One,
    Two
};

public enum DEF
{
    Zero,
    One,
    Two
};

public void TestEnum(Enum myEnum)
{
    ...
}
```

The function TestEnum takes any enumerator.  How can I test which one of the two does the passed in parameter belong to?  I could blindly start testing it out with try / catch casting but sheesh that's ugly.  Any cleaner ways of doing this?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I test which one of the two does the passed in parameter belong to?

You can just call `GetType`:

```
Type type = myEnum.GetType();
```

It's not clear what you want to *do* with it after that, mind you.

Alternatively:

```
if (myEnum is ABC)
{
}
else if (myEnum is DEF)
{
}
```

EDIT: If you're able to change the method signature *and* if your callers will know the type, then as per Jeppe's comment, you could use:

```
public void TestEnum<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    // Use typeof(T) here
}
```

You can't constrain `T` to be an enum type with normal C#... although there are [hacky ways](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) of writing code with such constraints applied via post-processing.

Comment: Jesus crist Jon, I can't even accept your answer for another 12 minutes.  Did you read my mind and wrote it out before I even posted this? Lol.  Expect a checkmark as soon as I can, thank you kindly for the lightning fast response, and applogies for such a dumb trivial question >.<

Comment: @Lukas You could also make your method generic. This goes like so: `public void TestEnum<TEnum>(TEnum myEnum) where TEnum : struct { /* method body here */ }`. This avoids boxing. You can then get the type with `typeof(TEnum)` for example. The problem with this is that the C# language does not currently allow you to constrain the type parameter `TEnum` to be ... an enum.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I'll add that option. (I'd assumed the method signature was fixed.) You might want to look at my Unconstrained Melody library too :) https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Skeet already nailed this but!

What about two methods.

```
public void TestEnum(ABC abcEnum) {
    //do ABC stuff
}

public void TestEnum(DEF defEnum) {
    //do DEF stuff
}
```

You get the branching you need but without having to worry about getting the if statement right.  True it's only an if statement but what if you add enum GHI.  Now there's some unaccounted for input for TestEnum to handle.  Using overloaded methods you'd catch that while compiling (or even better, intellisense would catch you).

Comment: There are many correct answers and although I like and am using Jon's I will give you a point since it is correct.